# Why is 'this' different than obj.var

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am currently writing an extensible plugin for jQuery. You can see the plugin [here](http://imaverage.com/hautforms/).

My question is specific to lines 37 and 96:

```
// Creates a Namespace
hautD = {};

// A Basic Dropdown Constructor function
hautD.HautForms = function(el, options) {
    // Overwrite default options 
    // with user provided ones 
    // and merge them into "options". 
    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    if (el) {
        this.init(el, options);
    }
} 

switch(options.cornerType){
    default:
    // default = 'rounded'
    if(this.borderRadius){
        alert('woo hoo');   
    }
    break
}
```

([source](http://imaverage.com/hautforms/js/jquery.hautdropdowns.js)) where I have `this.borderRadius`. When I set a breakpoint for this.borderRadius, it is undefined. So in the Chrome Inspector I set a watch expression for 'this' and it returns hautD.HautForms. If I set a watch inspection for `hautD.HautForms.borderRadius` the returned value is 'true'.

In a nutshell: why is `this.borderRadius == undefined` while `hautD.HautForms.borderRadius == true` given `this == hautD.HautForms`.

Sorry if this question is convoluted, this is my first 'real' plugin.

Comment: You should include relevant sections of your code with your question rather than just linking to the source. It will provide a reference in the event the links die one day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this is a special keyword that is used in methods to refer to the
>   object on which a method is being invoked

**this** is used **inside** the class object to access member variables.

Otherwise, you access your object from outside by public methods/variables.

In your code, you use this correctly here:

```
this.init(el, options);
```

because it is **inside** hautD.HautForms operation

Your code should be like this:

```
hautD.HautForms = function(el, options) {
    // Overwrite default options 
    // with user provided ones 
    // and merge them into "options". 
    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    if (el) {
        this.init(el, options);
    }

    switch(options.cornerType) {
       // here you can use this.borderRadius instead of hautD.HautForms.borderRadius from outside
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the concept, but if 'this' returns the object, why won't this.var be the same as object.var?

Comment: because you're not in the same scope

Comment: Ok, it's making more sense to me, and your provided code does what I want. Thanks! I'll accept the answer when it will let me.

Comment: @Matthew: Note that `options` is still not in the scope of the `switch` statement. Did you intend for the `switch` statement to be in the constructor? That seems to make more sense to me and then `this` would work as well.

Comment: @Felix - Yea, I see what you're saying. Moving the switch into the constructor makes more sense. Then I assume I would access the options in the same way Justin had me access that borderRadius var. Thanks for the advice.